# How to do many to many code first when foreign key does not contain full primary key

Tags: c#, many-to-many, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to model a many to many relationship. This is my context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Description>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.DescriptionID, e.Language });
});
modelBuilder.Entity<Company>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.CompanyID);
});

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasKey(cd => new { cd.CompanyID, cd.DescriptionID });
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasOne(cd => cd.Company)
    .WithMany(c => c.CompanyDescriptions)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CompanyID);
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasOne(cd => cd.Description)
    .WithMany(c => c.CompanyDescriptions)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.DescriptionID);
```

CompanyDescription is the cross table.
Both Company and Description contain

```
public ICollection<CompanyDescription> CompanyDescriptions { get; set; }
```

A company can have many descriptions and a description can have many companies. The way the database is currently set up is that a description does not contain a foreign key and a company only contains 'DescriptionID', but not language. So this 'foreign key' does not agree with the primary key of the description.
Because of that I get:

> The relationship from 'CompanyDescription.Description' to
>   'Description.CompanyDescriptions' with foreign key properties
>   {'DescriptionID' : int} cannot target the primary key
>   {'DescriptionID' : int, 'Language' : string} because it is not
>   compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign
>   key properties for this relationship.

What is the best way to fix this problem?

Edit, the model classes:

```
public partial class Company
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public int DescriptionID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyDescription> CompanyDescriptions { get; set; }
}
public partial class Description
{
    public int DescriptionID { get; set; }
    public ICollection<CompanyDescription> CompanyDescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

The cross table:

```
public class CompanyDescription
{
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }
    public RN_Company Company { get; set; }
    public int DescriptionID { get; set; }
    public string Language { get; set; }
    public Description Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Typically you add both PKs as FKs in the cross table, so is there a reason you don't have `Language` in the `CompanyDescription` table?  Also why is `Language` part of the PK of `Description`?

Comment: While this isn't the most intuitive solution, you could always uncouple the classes, and then when you go to load data from the database you add code to do a custom lookup on the secondary table. Again, not the most intuitive way to handle this, but I'm not sure there's another way around having that relationship without the columns matching exactly.

Comment: @Wouter Show your `Description` and `Company` model classes please!

Comment: I've added the model classes to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is `many-to-many` relationship between `Company` and `Description`, `Company` should not contain either `DescriptionID` or both `DescriptionID` and `Language`. As you said *company only contains 'DescriptionID', but not language*. Then please remove the `DescriptionID` from the `Company` model class.

Then your `CompanyDescription` entity should be as follows:

```
public class CompanyDescription
{
   public int CompanyID {get; set;}

   public int DescriptionID {get; set;}
   public string Language  {get; set;}

   public Company Company {get; set;}
   public Description Description {get; set;}
}
```

Then your `CompanyDescription` entity configuration should be as follows:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasKey(cd => new { cd.CompanyID, cd.DescriptionID, cd.Language }); // <-- Here it is

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasOne(cd => cd.Company)
    .WithMany(c => c.CompanyDescriptions)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.CompanyID);

modelBuilder.Entity<CompanyDescription>()
    .HasOne(cd => cd.Description)
    .WithMany(c => c.CompanyDescriptions)
    .HasForeignKey(bc => new { bc.DescriptionID, bc.Language}); // <-- Here it is
```

Comment: When I do this, the error is gone, but no data gets loaded when using next query:
var company = await _dbContext.RN_Company.Where(comp => comp.CompanyID == companyId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
I was hoping that Company.CompanyDescription would be filled with the Descriptions that have the key DescriptionID of Company.

Comment: You have to use `.Include` and `.ThenInclude` to load the related entities like `await _dbContext.RN_Company.Where(comp => comp.CompanyID == companyId).Include(comp => comp.CompanyDescription).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`. For more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data

Comment: Now I get this error: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'CompanyDescription'.

Comment: Its `CompanyDescriptions` not `CompanyDescription`. There is an extra `s`

Comment: I fixed that (otherwise it wouldn't compile). This happens when executing the code. The only thing that is named 'CompanyDescription' is the join class itself.
This actually makes sense, because this entity does not exist in the databse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191639/discussion-between-wouter-and-tanvirarjel).